# Travis-CI `Android 28 licenses have not been accepted`

Tags: android, gradle, build, yaml, travis-ci

I'm trying to build android project using Travis using `android-28` and `build-tools-28.0.0` but no matter what I do I get

```
>Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
     build-tools;28.0.0 Android SDK Build-Tools 28
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
```

during compiling.

I've tried:

- adding:

  ```yaml
  components:
    - build-tools-28.0.0
    - android-28
  ```
- installing through:

  ```
  echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --filter build-tools-28.0.0,android-28,extra-android-m2repository
  ```
- accepting licenses using:

  ```
  yes | sudo $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
  ```
- accepting licenses using:

  ```yaml
  licenses:
    - 'android-sdk-preview-license-52d11cd2'
    - 'android-sdk-license-.+'
    - 'google-gdk-license-.+'
  ```
- even manually writing to file inside `$ANDROID_SDK/licenses`.

I'm pretty sure that 2 weeks ago it was working completely normal, but now it just throwing this error everytime.

[PR in question](https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB/pull/25) so you can look at errors, builds and files.

Answer (score 31):

Add code below to your `.travis.yml` file

```yaml
before_install:
  - yes | sdkmanager "platforms;android-28"
```

or

```yaml
before_install:
  - chmod +x gradlew
  - mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses" || true
  - echo -e "\n8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license"
  - echo -e "\n84831b9409646a918e30573bab4c9c91346d8abd" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-preview-license"
  - yes | sdkmanager --update
  - yes | sdkmanager --licenses
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me. Even though I'm using SDK level 27, I started getting this error.

Comment: I got this error, even though I'm using SDK 29. However, the solution worked.